# Setting Color Using Number in C#

Tags: c#, .net, text, color-scheme

I can set a colors to object using Brush as follows:

```
Brushes.Red
```

How to apply the same using numbers,

say,

```
SetColor("#ffffff");
```

The above is an imaginary example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF:

```
var x = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#faffff");
```

Comment: What if I want to assign it to an Object that accepts Brush type. Say. Background property of a Run in RichTextBox.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz, You have to create appropriate brush, e.g.: `var brush = new SolidColorBrush(x);`

Comment: @ShamimHafiz, For WPF it is the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ColorTranslator.FromHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx)

EDIT - In response to your comment, you can create a brush based on your colour:

```
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: How to Assign it to Type Brush and not Color?

Answer (score 4):

You can make Brushes with your own Color:

```
Color col = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(col);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Color color = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
```

i assume you know how to calculate the values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx) method. It has an overload that allows specifying the color as an integer number.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color c = (Color)((new ColorConverter()).ConvertFromString("#ffffff"));
```